# How to extract all server conf file from nginx.conf with so many included files?

Tags: bash, nginx

I have a nginx conf file which has a lot of included conf files.I need to find come server configuration in these files.So can I extract server configuration from the included files by a script ?

Comment: Use a sripting language with easy to use and advanced text processing, like python.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: The command `nginx -T` displays the entire configuration including any included files.